# "Searching for devices..." when I try to run a new nativescript-vue project?

Tags: vuejs2, nativescript

[image]

I create a nativescript-vue project which following the official start guide [here](https://nativescript-vue.org/en/docs/getting-started/quick-start/)

But when I try to start and preview it on the browser...Nothing I can get from the terminal except "Searching for devices..."

I'm new to it, can someone give me some help on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`nativescript-vue` is searching for a **mobile** devices connected to your environment (or emulators). Nothing will happen in the browser as this is a mobile development framework. To test it attach a real mobile device (Android or iOS but for iOS, you will need MAC and provision profiles & certificates) or create an emulator/simulator and give it a go.

Comment: OK. Thanks for the answer. Is there a way I can test it on the browser? I mean its not very convenient if I develop a web project always with at least two devices on my desk.

Comment: For web development you should use Vue.js .. nativescript-vue is a plugin that enables NativeScript to work with Vue.js. That said there is no way to test a mobile application in the browser. If you want just to evaluate the technology you could use the Playground https://play.nativescript.org/